# Scala: Can a code block be converted to a closure?

Tags: scala, closures

Is something like the following Scala code example possible?

```
{ println("done!") }.asInstanceOf[() => Any]
```

What would be the most concise way to achive this?

**Edit:** My aim is to get a shorter expression of a closure than () => {...}. I want to get rid of the *() =>* part.

**Edit 2:** To give you a little use case example:

```
implicit class Closure(func: () => Any) {
  def asRunnable = new Runnable { override def run() = func() }
  def asThread   = new Thread(asRunnable)
  def run        = asThread.start()
}
(() => println("something")).run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use by-name parameters for this:

```
def block[A](f: => A): () => A = () => f

block { println("done!") }
```

except `block` is not shorter than `() =>` and a shorter name would be less clear (IMO).

Your use case would become

```
implicit class Closure(func: => Any) {
  def asRunnable = new Runnable { override def run() = func }
  def asThread   = new Thread(asRunnable)
  def run        = asThread.start()
}
```

Of course if the block's type already has the method you call, the conversion won't be applied! E.g. `{ new Runnable { def run() = ... } }.run` won't start a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
val f1 = () => println("done!") // () => Unit = <function0>

val f2 : () => Any = () => println("done!") // with explicit type () => Any = <function0>
```

Comment: Nice, but I that's not exactly what I wanted. I added some note to my question for clarification.

Comment: A clumsy way to achieve conversion of a code block to a closure would also be fine, since this could eventually be done by some implicit conversion if you know what I mean.

Comment: @GerhardHagerer yea, I understand. could you show a sample of usage such code?

Comment: I added a use case example to my question.